# Treat Edges between the same nodes as different

Tags: python, networkx

I'm using networkx to create graphs from edges which are pairs of nodes.  The problem is that sometimes the pairs repeat but they are a seperate edge.

So in the example below, each link is a seperate hop, we send traffic from c:3 to d:4 as STM-16 and it comes back groomed down to STM-4 back to c:3 where it is sent on to e:5.  So I want to render this all in a straight line.

Each link between two nodes is distinct and has a seperate link label

Example:

```
edgeList=[]

start_time = time.time() 

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edges_from([
(('a:1'), ('b:2'), {'link':'one'}),
(('b:2'), ('c:3'), {'link':'two'}),
(('c:3'), ('d:4'), {'link':'three'}),
(('d:4'), ('c:3'), {'link':'four'}),
(('c:3'), ('e:5'), {'link':'five'})
])

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.savefig("path.png")
plt.show()
```

This gives me:
[graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8uQn.png)

What I am looking for is a straight line, I want to go from

a:1>>b:2>>c:3>>d:4>>c:3>>e:5

In a straight line rather than fork at C3

I can't use DiGraph because I don't have direction, I have an unordered collection of (node1, node2, linkname)

Also, I can't change the node names, they are used later to pull in a set of node attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You violated a basic property of a graph: that a given label uniquely identifies a node.  You told `networkx` to go "back to c:3", and it did exactly what you told it.

First, understand the nature of a graph: all of these edges exist at the same time.  There is no linear sequencing in the picture when you draw the graph.  There is no "back to", merely an edge with an arrow on one end.

Your basic graph-theory contradiction is here:

```
we send traffic from c:3 to d:4 as STM-16
and it comes back groomed down to STM-4 
back to c:3 where it is sent on to e:5
```

You gave two different nodes the same label.  IN graph terms, that means that they *are* the same state, but your description makes it clear that you expect different actions.  In short, make up your mind.  If they require different actions, then they are different states, and you *must* describe them as such in your graph specification.  If you have a factory that happens to put those two steps in the same physical location, then that's your problem in factory construction, not the worry of this graphing utility.  :-)

I see two basic alternatives:

(1) Label your steps descriptively.  Coming back to location `c` is actually step 5, not a return to step 3.

```
G.add_edges_from([
(('a:1'), ('b:2'), {'link':'one'}),
(('b:2'), ('c:3'), {'link':'two'}),
(('c:3'), ('d:4'), {'link':'three'}),
(('d:4'), ('c:5'), {'link':'four'}),
(('c:5'), ('e:6'), {'link':'five'})
])
```

(2) Give `networkx` a label that describes things in *your* terms, but using decorations that don't display:

```
G.add_edges_from([
(('a:1'), ('b:2'), {'link':'one'}),
(('b:2'), ('c:3'), {'link':'two'}),
(('c:3'), ('d:4'), {'link':'three'}),
(('d:4'), (' c:3 '), {'link':'four'}),
((' c:3 '), ('e:5'), {'link':'five'})
])
```

I'm not certain this will fool `networkx` in particular, but give it a try.  If that doesn't work, try an underscore or period.  At worst, perhaps "c:3.1" and "c:3.2" would satisfy your needs.

Comment: OK, thanks.  So I was hoping that I could do this in a more edge centric way, as my edge labels are unique but if that's not possible, then I guess I need to think of a way to construct the edges with unique node hops and map the node names on as attributes.